# "Can't write unknown attribute" to HABTM join table when using custom foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

A User can HABTM Games and a Game can HABTM Users as Storytellers, to differentiate them from a later relationship where a Game will have many Users as Participants.

Rails throws the error "can't write unknown attribute `user_id'" when I attempt to add the user-input User objects to @game.storytellers via the create method in the Games controller.

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in my last migration (at the bottom of this post).

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :games, association_foreign_key: "storyteller_id"
end
```

models/game.rb

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :storytellers, class_name: "User", 
                                           foreign_key: "storyteller_id"
    attr_accessor :storyteller_group
end
```

controllers/games.rb

```
  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    @game.storytellers << params[:game][:storyteller_group].split(",").collect { |n| User.find_by(name: n) }

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

views/games/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>
    [snip]

    <!-- Additional storytellers-->
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :storyteller_group, id: "create-game" %>
        <div class="input">
            <%= f.text_field :storyteller_group, value: current_user.name %>
        </div>
    </div>

    [snip]
<% end %>
```

db/migrations/create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.index :name

      t.string :email
      t.index :email

      [snip]

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrations/create_games.rb

```
Class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :source

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrations/games_users.rb

```
class GamesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :game, index: true
      t.integer :storyteller_id, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written your HABTM foreign keys definitions in just the opposite way. Quoting from [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference):

> `:association_foreign_key`
>
> By convention, Rails assumes that the column in the join table used to hold the foreign key **pointing to the other model** is the name of that model with the suffix _id added. The :association_foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign key directly.

and

> `:foreign_key`
>
> By convention, Rails assumes that the column in the join table used to hold the foreign key **pointing to this model** is the name of this model with the suffix _id added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign key directly

So, the following should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games, foreign_key: "storyteller_id"
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :storytellers, class_name: "User", 
                                         association_foreign_key: "storyteller_id"
end
```